# Find all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(n+2) \mid (n^2+5)$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I'm trying to find all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$(n+2) \mid (n^2+5)$

as the title says, I've tried numbers up to $20$ and found that $1, 7$ are solutions and I suspect that those are the only $2$ solutions, however I have no idea how to show that.

I've done nothing but basic transformations:

$(n+2) \mid (n^2+5)$

$\iff n^2+5 = k(n+2)$

$\iff n^2+5 \mod(n+2) = 0$

$\iff (n^2 \mod(n+2) + 5 \mod(n+2)) \mod(n+2) = 0$

Now I suspect the next step is to find all possible solutions for

$n^2 \mod(n+2)$, which I have no idea how to do.

Comment: $n^2+5=(n^2-4)+9=(n-2)(n+2)+9$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$n+2\left|n^2+5\right. \implies k(n+2) = n^2+5 \implies k = \frac{n^2+5}{n+2}$$
Use that $$k = \frac{n^2+5}{n+2}=n-2+\frac{9}{n+2}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$(n+2)|(n^2-4)$$
Then $$n+2|(n^2+5)-9$$
Then $$n+2|9$$

Answer (score 1):

$(n+2) \mid (n^2+5)\implies \exists m \in \mathbb N$ such that :
$$\frac{n^2+5}{n+2}= m \iff n^2-mn+(5-2m)=0$$

By Solving the quadratic equation in $n$, We get:
$$n = \frac{m\pm \sqrt{m^2-20+12m}}{2}$$
Now since $n\in \mathbb N \implies m^2-20+12m$, Must be a perfect square:
$$m^2+12m-20 = x^2 \iff (m+6)^2-x^2=56$$
$$(m+6-x)(m+6+x)=56$$
You can look at the Factors of $56$ and try to solve the systems of equations, but you will end up with :
$$(m,x) \in \{(9,13), (3,5)\}$$
By Plugging the values of $m$ to the quadratic equation you will get :
$$n  \in \{1,7\}$$

I think that solving the quadratic equation is extremely useful in questions about perfect squares or divisibility.